# How do you get a reference to the drop view in DropDelegate?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In `DropDelegate` there's a method...

```
func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {}
```

`DropInfo` has a `location` property, which is a `CGPoint`.

The docs say...

> The location of the drag in the coordinate space of the drop view.

How do you get a reference to the drop view? Why didn't they supply this reference? Is it me or is that strange?

Comment: There is no view references in SwiftUI, work with view model instead.

Comment: How? All you have to go on is a set of coordinates?

Comment: @Asperi You can have view references in Swift. For example, I can have `let s = Spacer()` and then use `s` in the render function.

Comment: `Spacer` is a struct, so your `s` is a *value* of Spacer type. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html or https://www.raywenderlich.com/9481-reference-vs-value-types-in-swift

Comment: That's a very good point. How about using an `inout` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the view conform to `DropDelegate` and then use state variables to store what you need to perform your calculations, for instance with a `GeometryReader`:

```
struct MyView: View, DropDelegate {
    @State private var someWidth: CGFloat = .zero

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
        Text("My title")
            .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: self)
            .onAppear {
                someWidth = geometry.size.width
            }
        }
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        // Here do what you need with your state variable someWidth
        return true
    }
}
```